# SocketIO doesn't emit in iOS client

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm a socketIO newbie sort of, I've used socketIO sometime before and understand its concept but this is really new to me. I can connect to the server fine, however, in the callback method for the .connect event, it sort of skips the emit code line, like I didnt put it there. I know it's not emitting because I'm listening (for an event the server should emit to the client after it gets my (the client's) emit)just after the socket connects and then emit after listening, I get a response when using postman so I know it's something with my code. The TripSocketHandler class is a copy/paste from another class that also uses SocketIO, that other class emits fine but this one wont even though i can't see the difference in their code, only difference is their url which is not the problem because they both emit fine on postman with their respective urls.

```
TripSocketHandler.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
        tripSocket.on(clientEvent: .connect, callback: {data, ack in
            
            print("Trip socket connected")
            self.tripSocs() // This methods listens for the emitting event
            self.tripSocket.emit("requestStatus", self.statusObject)
            print(self.statusObject)
        })
```

This is that listening method

```
 func tripSocs() {
        
        tripSocket.on("requestAccepted" + "0f7f3821-0b3b-439e-8831-079e7f485b88", callback: {data, ack in
            
            let response = data[0] as! [String : Any]
            print("request accepted: \(response)")
            let status = response["status"] as! [String: Any]
```

Socket's customization

```
class TripSocketHandler: NSObject {
    
    
    static let sharedInstance = SocketHandler()
    let socket = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string:"https://123456789.com")!, config: [.log(false), .compress])
    var mSocket: SocketIOClient!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        mSocket = socket.defaultSocket
    }

    func getSocket() -> SocketIOClient {
        return mSocket
    }

    func establishConnection() {
        mSocket.connect()
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        mSocket.disconnect()
    }
}
```

[Postman successful response Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1u3c.png)
[Debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSt6y.png)

I attached some images for better understanding of the problem

Comment: Are you using the same version of Socket.io as the server?

Comment: I’m not sure, but the other class emits fine, so I’m guessing yes